# HTMLCollection adding different attributes affects the live collection differently, need explanation

Tags: javascript, dom, live

so we all know `document.getElementsByClassName` and `document.getElementsByTagName` are live HTMLCollections.

I googled and can't seem to find the answer to this, maybe I just don't get it, who can explain it to me?

So I made 2 examples, one with adding a class attribute, the other with bgcolor. Why does the first act like expected and the other gets it's job done...

Why does the TagName one work differently even it's a HTMLCollection in the first example?

How can I know which will work normally and which wont??

https://jsfiddle.net/adkuca/84ryjp7s/2/

https://jsfiddle.net/adkuca/f1o9h7be/

```js
var ran = document.getElementsByClassName('wasd');
/*var ran = document.getElementsByTagName('td');*/

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', func);
function func() {
  console.log(ran); //HTMLCollection, all 6
    console.log(ran.length); //6 with both
    for (let i = 0; i < ran.length; i++) {
        ran[i].setAttribute("class", "green");
    }
    console.log(ran); //HTMLCollection, all 6 with TagName, every 2nd with ClassName
    console.log(ran.length); //6 with TagName, 3 with ClassName
}
```

```css
tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="btn">func</button>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
var ran = document.getElementsByClassName('wasd');
/*var ran = document.getElementsByTagName('td');*/

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', func);
function func() {
  console.log(ran); //HTMLCollection, all 6
    console.log(ran.length); //6 with both
    for (let i = 0; i < ran.length; i++) {
        ran[i].setAttribute("bgcolor", "green");
    }
    console.log(ran); //HTMLCollection, all 6
    console.log(ran.length); //6 with both
}
```

```css
tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="btn">func</button>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ran` in the first snippet has only three elements and not six as stated in the comment. Just check the content of `ran` after the `.setAttribte("class", ...)` line. The length will decrease by one after every round in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both work normally and in the same way. The className appears to work differently because you're effectively removing elements from the list you're working with, while you're going through it.

when you use `setAttribute("class", "green");` you're replacing the "wasd" class with "green"

This will work if you add a class instead of replacing the current one using `ele.classList.add(class)`

https://jsfiddle.net/84ryjp7s/3/

Comment: @WASD If this is the answer you were looking for there is a checkmark next to the post. Click it to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ok to sum it up for ppl who might have same question.

so if you get a collection with ClassName, means everything will be behaving normally untill you remove the current class you gathered the collection with.

if it was class="a b", you can add any class, but if you delete/change 1 of those it ruins the HTML collection

Same with any other HTMLCollection / live NodeList

if you gather with getElementsByTagName, you can change class but you can't change the td's, if you try to remove the div, you ruined the collection

https://jsfiddle.net/adkuca/c00fqmts/

as it counts you're removing td's, therefore chaning the HTML collection, shrinking it by 1, therefore shrinking the ran.length by 1, so you get half iterations, and you add a new td half less.

examine this:  https://jsfiddle.net/adkuca/c7jb0es8/

but if you really want to do gather classes with classname and then change them, you can store them into an array and then change.

```
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('wasd')).forEach(function(itm){
    itm.setAttribute('replaced-wasd');
});
```

```js
var ran = document.getElementsByClassName('wasd');
/*var ran = document.getElementsByTagName('td');*/

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', func);
function func() {
  console.log(ran); //HTMLCollection, all 6
    console.log(ran.length); //6 with both
    for (let i = 0; i < ran.length; i++) {
      console.log(ran.length);
        ran[i].setAttribute("class", "green");
        console.log(ran.length);
        console.log("i = " + i);
        console.log(ran);
    }
    console.log(ran); //HTMLCollection, all 6 with TagName, every 2nd with ClassName
    console.log(ran.length); //6 with TagName, 3 with ClassName
}
```

```css
tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="btn">func</button>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
            <td class="wasd"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```